# insert and remove multiple values in a table created with SET sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a SET sql table, so a row can contain multiple values: Foo_1 Foo_2 Foo_3.

The above query run but it will update the the row and set just one value.

`QueryType` valid values are 1 2 or 3

```
"UPDATE Foo_status
    SET type = 'Foo_%s',
       status = %d
    WHERE name ='%s'
", queryType.c_str(),status,GetName()
```

When i run the query: Let's assume that `QueryType` is `1`, it's working.. my type row will have `Foo_1`, but when i run again the query and `Foo` has `QueryType`  `2`, it will remove `Foo_1` and add `Foo_2`

How i can change my query so when i run the query it will continue to update values ?

Example:
Run Query

```
 -Add Foo_1
```

Run Query

```
-Add Foo_2
```

Table struct

```
CREATE TABLE `Foo_status` (
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `type` set('Foo_1','Foo_2','Foo_3') CHARACTER SET latin2 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I tried to search for an solution but without succes, that's i asked here.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve the immediate problem at hand, but if the data you're updating is derived *in any way* from external sources (say: from the user), then this is an SQL injection nightmare waiting to happen.  Be sure to consider prepared queries if the data is not fully trusted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple set elements are specified using a comma-separated string. To add a new value, you have to concatenate a string beginning with comma.

```
"UPDATE Foo_status
    SET type = CONCAT(type, ',Foo_%s'),
       status = %d
    WHERE name ='%s'
", queryType.c_str(),status,GetName()
```

To remove a value from a `SET`, use `REPLACE()`:

```
"UPDATE Foo_status
    SET type = REPLACE(type, 'Foo_%s', ''),
       status = %d
    WHERE name ='%s'
", queryType.c_str(),status,GetName()
```

It would be easier if you normalized your schema and used a table with a separate row for each `type`, instead of using the `SET` datatype. This would also allow you to add an index that would make searching for specific set values more efficient.

Comment: Thank you, a way to remove it do you have? Please, i'm gonna need :D

Comment: Yes, this.  Every time I've tried to cheat by treating a single field as having multiple values for "just one quick thing" I've been burned and had to refactor to do it properly.

Comment: @IrinelIovan Added removing

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a set wirh this. Here written for select. 
You can it also use for UPDATE.
You only must change the string to remove

```
    select t,
trim( BOTH ',' FROM 
     replace (concat (',',t,','),',Foo_2,',',')) as new_t
from F;
```

Sample: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8b041/2